# Accepting an Excel file with io stream

Tags: python, excel, io, xlrd

Currently I am working on an Excel file and taking its path as input as

```
myObj = ProcessExcelFile("C:\SampleExcel.xlsx")
```

constructor is as

```
def __init__(self, filepath):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        raise FileNotFoundError(filepath)

    self.datawb = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)
```

but now from another interface I want to use the same class but its not sending me filepath its sending me file through io stream as

```
data = req.stream.read(req.content_length)
file = io.BytesIO(data)
```

now this file variable when I am passing in my file as

```
myObj = ProcessExcelFile(file)
```

It's giving me error

```
TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not _io.BytesIO
```

I want to make my init so that it can take path as well as an io stream or if its not possible, I need to have file from io stream as priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to modify your class to allow streams as well. Pass the stream to `open_workbook` via `file_contents`.

```
def __init__(self, filepath, stream=False):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''
    if stream:
        self.datawb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=filepath.read())    
    else:        
        if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
            raise FileNotFoundError(filepath)
        self.datawb = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)
```

Comment: in this case if I pass a stream it will still fall in FileNot found exception right ? do I need to put that in else part

Comment: Yep, I just realized the same copy&paste mistake. I'll update the answer.

Comment: it worked ! tanks a lot ! I m sorry but this simple thing I was not able to google it correctly